# How to remove attached files from amazon s3 server when the corresponding resource is deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, ckeditor

I have a question model which can be created using the ckeditor gem with Paperclip.
Each question can contain several attached pictures.
Each question has several answers and each answer can contain several attached pictures too (answers are created with ckeditor too).

The configuration for my ckeditor uploaded pictures is the following :

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
                :storage => :s3,
                :url  => ":s3_eu_url",
                :s3_credentials => "path to credentials",
                :path => ":class/:id/:basename.:extension",
                  :styles => {  :medium => "500x500>",
                                :thumb => "500x500>"},
                :s3_protocol => 'http'

validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 2.megabytes
validates_attachment_presence :data

def url_content
  url(:content)
end
end
```

With that configuration I do not know how to identify the pictures attached to a given question or answer. The aim is to remove the pictures from s3 when the question or the answer is deleted.

Comment: How are you deleting the record in the first place?

Comment: @question.destroy in the destroy method of my QuestionsController.

Comment: Is there some callback filter blocking the destroy action? Try running the `delete!` method on the attachment in the console, and see if it's removed from the server, and likewise with the `destroy` method.

Comment: I tried to delete and destroy the resources from the console but it does not delete the attached picture from S3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I did not succeed in finding a solution to this problem using Paperclip, I start to use [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) that provides this functionality.